# how ruby if column less than 4 print column 3?

Tags: ruby, linux

Im triying to use this code but not work

```
  ruby -a -F';' -ne   if $F[2]<4    'puts $F[3]'  ppp.txt
```

this is my file

```
mmm;2;nsfnjd
sadjjasjnsd;6;gdhjsd
gsduhdssdj;3;gsdhjhjsd
```

what is doing worng Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, instead of treating Ruby like some kind of fancy Perl and writing scripts like that, let's expand it into the Ruby code equivalent for clarity:

```
$; = ';'

while gets
  $F = $_.split

  if $F[2]<4
    puts $F[3]
  end
end
```

Your original code doesn't work, it can't possibly work because it's not valid Ruby code, and further, you're not properly quoting it to pass through the `-e` evaluation term. Trying to run it I get:

```
-bash: 4: No such file or directory
```

You're also presuming the array is 1-indexed, but it's not. It's 0-indexed. Additionally Ruby treats integer values as completely different from strings, never equivalent, not auto-converted. As such you need to call `.to_i` to convert.

Here's a re-written program that does the job:

```
File.open(ARGV[0]) do |fi|
  fi.readlines.each do |line|
    parts = line.chomp.split(';')

    if parts[1].to_i < 4
      puts parts[2]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved with this

```
 ruby -a -F';' -ne   '   if $F[1] < "4"  ;puts  $F[2] end '  ppp.txt
```